# How to write the command line input into the command in batch?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting, windows-scripting

I want to run the command

```
ex.exe property
```

where 'property' is the text which I first enter from the command line. How to write such batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a prompt for a variable value. Try something like:

```
set /p property=Enter Property:
ex.exe %property%
```

Answer (score 1):

what you want are command line arguments - e.g. the first one

```
ex.exe %1
```

see [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php) for more details